# Company wants to hire no more then $140$ workers. There are $450$ people taking test. Probability of passing test is $0.3$

Tags: probability, random-variables

Company wants to hire no more then $140$ workers. Competence test is being held, there are $450$ people taking it. Probability of passing test is $0.3$, whats the probability that company will have problems with excess candidaties?

**I have trouble with this task, could anyone suggest further steps?**

$X$-Number of people that passed the test is random variable with binomial distribution. Parameters $n=450$, $p=0.3$

$$P(X>140)=1-P(X\leq 140)$$

**@Edit**

Normal distribution

$N(135;9,72(1))$

$X\leq 140 = P(U\leq0.51)=\Phi(0.51)=0.69065$

$\Phi$ is distribution  of $N(0;1)$ so $(PX>140)=1-0.6965=0.3035$

Comment: Ok, you know its a binomial distribution, write down the general form for a binomial distribution

Comment: I think it's a binomial distribution, basically, you want upwards of 140 successes. I ran it on a binomial calculator and it is: P(X>140) = 0.2842123215

Comment: With $n=450$ and $p=0.3$ you can compute mean and standard deviation and approximate with standard normal distribution

Comment: @Alex could you check edit in main post?

Comment: Assuming you computer mean and sd correctly, seems fine

Comment: But the peak is around 135 so shouldn't Poisson aproximation be better?

Comment: I just read a tip from profesor that we are supposed to find value of standard normal distribution value from tables. Does it change the correctness of my post?