# Company wants to hire no more then 140 workers. There are 450 people taking test. Probability of passing test is 0.3

Tags: probability, random-variables

Company wants to hire no more then $140$ workers. Competence test is being held, there are $450$ people taking it. Probability of passing test is $0.3$, whats the probability that company will have problems with excess candidaties?

$X$-Number of people that passed the test is random variable with binomial distribution. Parameters $n=450$, $p=0.3$

$$P(X>140)=1-P(X\leq 140)$$

Normal distribution

$N(135;9,72(1))$

$X\leq 140 = P(U\leq0.51)=\Phi(0.51)=0.69065$

$\Phi$ is distribution  of $N(0;1)$ so $(PX>140)=1-0.6965=0.3035$

**I posted this task yesterday and people said it was correct, but after some time I noticed an additional description from profesor that said "find value of standard normal distribution from tables"**

**How should I use this in my answer?**

Comment: Previous question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3678321/company-wants-to-hire-no-more-then-140-workers-there-are-450-people-taking

Comment: Well where did you find
$$
\Phi(0.51) = 0.69064
$$
?